# Preposition At + Place and/or At + The + Place

Tags: grammar, prepositions, articles, descriptive-grammar

I know that I can use this structure:

I AM + AT + THE + NAME OF THE PLACE  + TYPE OF PLACE

For instance, I can say:

> - I'm at the Empire State Building
> - I'm at the Hilton Hotel

However, can we remove the article THE before the name of the place?
For instance, can I say:

> - Join us at Paris University for this great event
> - Book your room at Hyatt Paris now
> - We will host an event at Accord Arena in Paris

Comment: In many cases, it sounds odd to unacceptable to leave out the definite article (*I'll meet you at Chrysler Building). But with some names, where the inclusion of the article might be considered to sound rather stuffy, bloated, less snappy (and especially in the States), it is fairly common to omit it. I'll meet you at Circus Circus / Planet Hollywood / Caesars Palace / Bally's (but the Stratosphere / the Venetian).  Usage may also vary with actual example: 'She's at the University of Leicester' but 'It's a University of Leicester publication'.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you.
Makes sense to me. But from a grammatical and formal perspective, should I write
- I'll meet you at the Planet Hollywood?

Answer (score 0):

The preposition is just *at* -- the rest is a separate part of the sentence.

The need for an article, definite (*the*), indefinite (*a*) or none, depends on the noun or noun clause that follows, not on the preposition.

Comment: Thank you. 
So based on Edwin's examples, what's grammatically correct?
- I'll meet you at Planet Hollywood
or
- I'll meet you at the Planet Hollywood?

I'm asking regardless how it sounds orally.